# The set of continuous map from $X$ to $K$ is separable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> $\mathbf QUESTION :$ Show that $C_K$(X) , the set of all continuous functions from $X$ to $K$, with supremum norm is separable. Where $X$ is a compact , Hausdorff space and $K$ is a complete separable metric space.

I have showed that $Y = C_K(X)$ is a Banach space. Using taking a Cauchy sequence I have showed that the sequence is uniformly Cauchy sequence . And as $K$ is complete so the uniform limit is continuous. Hence $Y$ is Banach . But in proof of separability I want to show that $Y$ has a subset which is countable and dense in $Y$.
but how can I prove that the existence on such subset.

Please help me.

Comment: Y cannot be a Banach space: addition and multiplication by a scalar are not defined for its elements.

Comment: You probably mean Y is a complete space. Also, finding a dense subset of Y is easy — just take Y. You probably mean a countable dense subset.

Comment: Even if you take $K=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, the resulting space is only separable if $X$ is metrizable.

Comment: As Y is normed linear space with respect to the supremum norm and Y is complete so Y is a Banach space.

Comment: As @MaoWao rightly said, you cannot show it: it's false as stated.

Comment: @TotuanDas How is Y a linear space? What is the zero vector, for instance?

Answer (score 3):

In case $X$ is a point (which is compact) then the space of continuous functions from $X$ to the metric space $K$, with the sup norm, is isometric (hence homeomorphic) to $K$ itself. In particular, if $K$ is not separable there is no hope to prove your claim. For metric spaces, separability is equivalent to second countability, and there exist complete metric spaces which are not second countables.

Comment: In fact, if $K = \Bbb R$, $C_K(X)$ is separable iff $X$ is compact metrisable.

Comment: I had forgot to mention that K is seperable . I was trying in similar way without saying $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ .